# How can I add negative delay to a Simulink function?

Tags: signal-processing, delay, simulink

Asume that you have a Simulink signal `signal1` (step / signal builder / ...). Is there a block that can build a signal `signal2` that is the original signal `signal1` shifted forwards in time: `signal2(t)=signal1(t+T)`? A delay allows only to have a signal that is shifted backwards in time.

- I know that you can use parameters in f.i. a step function and set them in a script. I just wondered whether a 'negative delay' block would exist.
- Shifting a signal backwards in time can be physically impossible (causal systems), but in some applications, it is meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to define a `signal0` that corresponds to `signal1` but is shifted backwards in time. Then both `signal1`and `signal2` can be determined by adding a suitable `transport delay` to `signal0`.